# How to hightlight part of the text in datagridview column?

Tags: c#, datagridview, colors, highlight

I have a search button which finds a particular text on button click. Now I want to hightlight the text that the user searched for not the entire text. How do I do it? This is my search code.

```
private void button7_Click_3(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  string filterBy;
  filterBy = "Stringtext Like '%" + textBox6.Text + "%'";
  ((DataTable)dataGridView1.DataSource).DefaultView.RowFilter = filterBy;
}
```

any ideas?

Comment: If you want a search as you type (like Google). Look here http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/138595/Search-As-You-Type-in-C#

Answer (score 1):

I don't think this functionality is available for winform controls yet, however `DevExpress` has this control `SearchLookUpEdit` that does exactly what you're trying to achieve. See [here](http://documentation.devexpress.com/#windowsforms/clsDevExpressXtraEditorsSearchLookUpEdittopic).